React doesn't work correctly after migration craco -> webpack
I did migration of application(what was worked correctly) from craco.config -> webpack.config for some reason, I managed to eliminate all the errors to run the application, however now it seems the react configuration was poorly configured and I have a console full of similar errors(see screenshot), but any file of application wasn't changed, only config. It's not a finished version, just in stage of trying to run application on localhost, but I have no idea what's wrong with React.

Here is my webpack config(webpack serve):
const path = require("path");
const platformDir = path.resolve("../../../../../platform-web");
const sourceDir = path.resolve("./src");
const publicDir = path.resolve("./public");
const resourcesFile = path.join(sourceDir, "styles/_resources.scss");
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
const { HotModuleReplacementPlugin } = require("webpack");

module.exports = {
  mode: "development",
  entry: path.join(sourceDir, "index.ts"),
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "build"),
    filename: "[name].[contenthash:8].js"
  },
  resolve: {
    mainFiles: ["index"],
    extensions: [".tsx", ".ts", ".js", ".jsx"],
    modules: [
      path.resolve("./src"), "./node_modules", path.join(platformDir, "./node_modules")],
    alias: {
      resources: resourcesFile,
      "@platform-web": path.resolve(__dirname, "../../../../../platform-web/src")
    },
  },
  plugins: [
    new HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: path.join(publicDir, "index.html")
    })
  ],
  module: {
    { rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(ts|tsx|js|jsx)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: { "babel-loader",
        },
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/i,
        { use: [ "style-loader", "css-loader",]
      },
      {
        test: /\.s[ac]ss$/i,
        { use: [
          { "style-loader",
          "css-loader",
          {
            loader: "sass-loader",
            options: {
              sassOptions: {
                includePaths: [path.resolve(platformDir, "./src/styles"), "./src/styles"],
              },
            },
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpe?g|woff2|)$/i,
        use: {
          loader: "file-loader"
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.svg$/,
        use: ["@svgr/webpack".]
      }
    ],
  },
  devServer: {
    port: 5100,
    hot: true,
    proxy: [{
      context: [ "/_api",]
      target: "https://some.url/",
      changeOrigin: true
    }],
  },

};

babel.config.js:
module.exports = {
  presets: [
    ["@babel/preset-env", {
      modules: false,
    },],
    ["@babel/preset-react", {"runtime": "automatic"}],
    "@babel/preset-typescript"
  ],
  plugins: [
    ["@babel/plugin-syntax-import-attributes", { "legacy": true }],
    ["@babel/plugin-transform-class-properties", { "loose": true }],
    ["@babel/plugin-transform-private-property-in-object", { "loose": true }],
    ["@babel/plugin-transform-private-methods", { "loose": true }]
  ]
};

old craco.config.js:
const path = require("path");
const CracoAlias = require("craco-alias");

const platformDir = path.resolve("../../../../platform-web");
const platformSrc = path.join(platformDir, "src");
const sourceDir = path.resolve("./src");
const resourcesFile = path.join(sourceDir, "styles/_resources.scss");

module.exports = {
  reactScriptsVersion: "react-scripts",
  plugins: [
    {
      plugin: CracoAlias,
      options: {
        source: "tsconfig",
        baseUrl: "./src",
        tsConfigPath: "./tsconfig.extend.json",
      },
    },
  ],
  style: {
    css: {
      loaderOptions: {
        modules: {
          auto: true,
          exportLocalsConvention: "camelCase",
        },
      },
    },
  },
  webpack: {
    configure: (cfg) => {
      const scopePluginIndex = cfg.resolve.plugins.findIndex(
        ({ constructor }) =>
          constructor && constructor.name === "ModuleScopePlugin"
      );

      cfg.resolve.modules = [
        sourceDir,
        path.resolve("./node_modules"),
        path.join(platformDir, "./node_modules"),
      ];
      cfg.resolve.alias = { resources: resourcesFile };
      cfg.resolve.plugins.splice(scopePluginIndex, 1);

      const oneOfRule = cfg.module.rules.find((rule) => rule.oneOf);
      const tsRule = oneOfRule.oneOf.find((rule) =>
        rule.test.toString().includes("ts|tsx")
      );

      tsRule.include = [sourceDir, platformSrc];
      tsRule.exclude = /node_modules/;

      return cfg;
    },
  },
  babel: {
    plugins: [
      ["@babel/plugin-syntax-import-attributes", { "legacy": true }],
      ["@babel/plugin-transform-class-properties", { "loose": true }],
      ["@babel/plugin-transform-private-property-in-object", { "loose": true }],
      ["@babel/plugin-transform-private-methods", { "loose": true }]
    ],
    presets: [
      ["@babel/preset-env", {
        modules: false, //Setting this to false will preserve ES services
      },],
      ["@babel/preset-react", {"runtime": "automatic"}],
      "@babel/preset-typescript"
    ],
  },
  devServer: {
    port: 5100,
    proxy: {
      "/_api": {
      target: "https://some.url/",
        secure: true,
        changeOrigin: true
      },
    },
  }
};

